# How to check if the paremeter exists in the url's page or not?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, parameters

I have an url looks like `www.mywebsite.com/item_id=abc`. Inside that url's page, there will be a parameter showing up feedback information if the item has feedback (e.g: `feedback_info`). Otherwise, there will be no that parameter. My task is to check each url like that and note if it has feedback or not. But there are too many urls to check by hand, so I need to create a tool that I can paste a bunch of that urls into it, then click check, if the url's page has `feedback_info` parameter, then publish the result `OK | url`. Otherwise, it doesn't show up the result. How can I do that? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Where is your code?? Please show us your efforts! Thanks

Comment: Hmm, I don't have the code and I'm a noob. That's why I'm asking for help with a clearly description. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write your code for you, but here are the pointers for PHP.

- Use `file_get_contents()` to fetch the HTML from the page.
- Use `strpos()` to see if a given string exists in the HTML.